# vlookup on multiple pages breaking don't know why

Tags: excel, vba

I have a command button on Start page and want to lookup with the value in F13 on the same page in the transaction page and if found copy row the value is in then paste it on sheet 3.

I've tried multiple ways latest attempt below.

Start page   - value for lookup in F13
Transaction page  - Search range in Column A
Sheet3 - where I want to put the result

Transaction table I put the value in F13 in A1 for testing. so it should find it.

it breaks at the A = Application... I know there is 1004 error, not sure if I'm doing it right, but put in some code in to hopefully handle the error.

I tried moving the on error above the a = application line but it ends up copying the current cell in the start page and pasting it in sheet3.

Sorry still new to vba a lot to learn... Any help would be great!

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
Dim WR As String
Dim Lookup_Range As Range
Dim a As String




WR = Sheets("Start page").Range("F13").Value

Set Lookup_Range = Sheets("TransactionTable").Range("A1:A4000")


' vlookup

a = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("F13"), Worksheets("TransactionTable").Range("A1:A4000"), 1, False)
On Error GoTo IGotNothing:

If a = WR Then

Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select

Selection.Copy


Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
    Exit Sub
 Else


  IGotNothing:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    n = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Resume Next
Else
    MsgBox ("No value found")
   End
End If


End If

End Sub
```

Comment: it is not finding the value in the lookup column.  Try putting the sheet parent in fron of the range: `.VLookup(Sheets("Start page").Range("F13"),...` but it will always error if the value is not found.  there are ways to manage the error.  Many examples can be found on this site.

Comment: What's `End`  in `IGotNothing`? Also when you put `On Error Goto IGotNothing:` remove the `:` at the end, otherwise I *think* VBA compiles those next lines as if you're declaring that GoTo...

Comment: You need to put the error catch in front of the vlookup line.

Comment: good info everyone thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `Dim a As Variant` instead of `Dim a As String` and use `Application.VLookup` instead of `WorksheetFunction.VLookup`. The advantage of this method is if VLookup returns an error, it will also be stored in the variable `a` else the code will execute normally. And if VLookup returns an error, error handling will take care of it.

Try it like this...

```
Dim a As Variant
a = Application.VLookup(Range("F13"), Worksheets("TransactionTable").Range("A1:A4000"), 1, False)
```

Comment: Slightly misleading. `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` will throw a run-time error that you can handle with standard/idiomatic VBA error handling, whereas `Application.VLookup` is a late-bound (no IntelliSense) implementation working off the extended `Application` interface that will *return* an error value as a `Variant` instead - which means if the lookup fails all you're doing is *failing later*, with a confusing "Type Mismatch" erorr, when later code assumes `a` can safely be treated as a `String`, or compared to one. Error handling *does not* pick up a failed late-bound lookup.

Comment: I add the variant changes and only vlookup and error before the vlookup

Comment: it looks like it doesn't catch the value and copy and paste. so weird why it doesn't. just goes to messagebox. also removed the ":" at first error line.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for all the help I learned a lot!

After a while I decided to try a different direction looks like I found something that will work.

I basically used a count. Thank you again for everyone that contributed!

```
 Private Sub CommandButton11_Click()

  a = Worksheets("TransactionTable").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 2 To a
 If Worksheets("TransactionTable").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Start page").Range("F13").Value Then
 Worksheets("TransactionTable").Rows(i).Copy
 Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
 b = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 Worksheets("Start page").Activate

 Else
 MsgBox "Workorder does not exist"

 End If


  Next
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Start page").Cells(1.1).Select

   End Sub
```